# Revisit/change agriculture tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems we are more [regularly](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24439/can-i-germinate-a-dehusked-and-dried-areca-nut) getting questions that are about agricultural techniques themselves, rather than connected to earth science topics.  I believe we are mostly in agreement that such questions are off topic here, as they are entirely remote from the core subjects we focus on here (from [here](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): meteorology, geophysics, geology, climatology, oceanography, geochemistry, and hydrology).

I think the issue if we are indeed the improper place for such questions lies in the lack of definition to the [agriculture tag](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agriculture).  The tag term itself is just generic "agriculture" and the tag description also fails to describe the earth science aspect I believe we intend

> The cultivation of food and materials, specifically from or derived
> from plants and animals using traditional or modern industrial
> practices.

Likewise there is a [question on mainsite Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295119/where-can-i-ask-agriculture-related-questions-and-will-there-be-a-site-on-se-fo) years ago that asks where agriculture questions are on topic, and the top answer suggests our site because of the generic tag definition.

I think if the goal is limit it to agriculture questions related to remote sensing, geography, and perhaps global warming, that we need to improve the tag.

I propose

- Renaming the tag to be clearer that it is not for general agricultural questions.  Perhaps "agriculture in earth sciences", or separate tags for each area of earth science it relates to (agricultural in remote sensing, agriculture in global warming, etc)?  I believe most users who make such posts use the tag (plus past questions, the Meta question, and a lack of understanding of the term earth science) as encouragement for posting such questions here.
- Rewording the tag definition.  Perhaps something as simple as:

> How agriculture, the cultivation of food and materials from plants and animals, affects and is investigated by the earth science fields such as meteorology, geophysics, geology, climatology, oceanography, geochemistry, and hydrology. This includes agricultural topics in remote sensing, climate change, and geographic distribution.  For plant growing questions consider [gardening & landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/), [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/), and [sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) stack exchanges.

(I don't know if there's a limit in the tag description length... it could be pruned if needed?)

This is just an initial proposal, hopefully can lead to better organization and interaction.  Feel to edit or propose alternatives.

Comment: (Is it just me, or are the tags fairly lacking in Meta here too?  No tag for "topicality" or "on-topic" or such?)

Comment: I think you're right about the lack of tags on Meta.

Comment: I agree with what you're written here. I also have the impression it's easy to make a tag but it's a lot more difficult to change a tag. I have issues with two tags that were recently created.

Comment: Yeah, [looks like it takes a moderator indeed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag) to rename the tag.  Changing the description should I imagine be straightforward.  Just have to get the attention of one of our moderators...

Comment: [All 3 moderators](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) have been online this week (seen by opening their profile), so they should be available at least occasionally.  My suggestion would be to go back and flag your post as "needs moderator attention" and tell them again what is needed.  And I will do the same if all opinions are positive/lacking here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to flag the question as needing moderator attention. I've just done that.